# C# get the min and max datetime of employee

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to ask for help i'm having trouble with Min and Max the time in and time out of employees.
The thing is employees need to swipe their cards to enter and exit the property so they will have multiple swipe in and out during their whole shift. Below is my code trying to figure out how to get the min and max time of entry and exit of the employee.

```
        TimeSpan minDuration = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01"); //minimum duration from entry to exit
        TimeSpan maxDuration = TimeSpan.Parse("14:00"); //maximum duration from entry to exit

        DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse("2021-1-10"); //From date range filter
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse("2021-1-12");   //To date range filter

        List<StaffComplianceList> setStaffComplianceList = new List<StaffComplianceList>();
        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 10, 05, 24, 09), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 3 Entry", EventType = "Door Access Granted" });
        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 10, 06, 13, 54), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 7 Exit", EventType = "Card Exit Granted" });
        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 10, 06, 54, 34), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 4 Entry", EventType = "Door Access Granted" });
        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 10, 14, 03, 24), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 5 Exit", EventType = "Card Exit Granted" });

        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 11, 18, 25, 09), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 3 Entry", EventType = "Door Access Granted" });
        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 11, 19, 00, 04), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 7 Exit", EventType = "Card Exit Granted" });
        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 11, 19, 24, 34), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 4 Entry", EventType = "Door Access Granted" });
        setStaffComplianceList.Add(new StaffComplianceList { EmployeeNumber = "2448", CardholderName = "Aziel Cai", OccurrenceTime = new DateTime(2021, 01, 12, 07, 03, 24), EventSource = "Staff Entrance Lane 5 Exit", EventType = "Card Exit Granted" });


        //Filter the list base on the date range value
        var staffList = setStaffComplianceList.Where(x => (x.OccurrenceTime.Date >= fromDate) && (x.OccurrenceTime.Date <= toDate)).ToList();

        var getMinAndMax = from stafflist in staffList
                           group stafflist by new { stafflist.OccurrenceTime.Date , stafflist.EmployeeNumber} into staffComplianceGroup
                           let f = staffComplianceGroup.FirstOrDefault()
                           select new
                           {
                               EmployeeNumber = f.EmployeeNumber,
                               CardholderName = f.CardholderName,
                               MinTime = staffComplianceGroup.Min(x => x.OccurrenceTime),
                               MaxTime = staffComplianceGroup.Max(x => x.OccurrenceTime),
                           };
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to monitor employees if they use the company staff entry point and exit point during their shift.

They can have multiple entry and exit for their whole shift due to the smoking area is outside the entry and exit.

I have a `minDuration` and `maxDuration` `TimeSpan`, what it does is user can filter the minimum duration and the maximum duration of employee before they exit the property to be tagged as compliant, From 1 minute to 14 hours I will capture their in and out it means including the smoking breaks will be captured. But those in and outs during their breaks is not important, what I need is the first entry and last so I can tagged them as compliant using the entry and exit point.

fromDate and toDate is filter of date range to process. I hope i clarify what i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why do you expect those results? If you group by `EmployeeNumber`, and they all have the same one, then `Min` is the smallest `OccurrenceTime`, and `Max` is the largest. Perhaps you also want to group by `OccurrenceTime.Date`? What are the values of `frolmDate` and `toDate`?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if a shift spans multiple days (crosses midnight)?

Comment: @RufusL I did group by Date but the issue is the night shift it returns two min and max one with the same day and the second is the date and time of exit.

Comment: @Yajnos yes please explain what the problem is you are trying to solve, and the complexities involved, ie any business rules

Comment: There is no `GroupBy` for `Occurrence.Date` in the code shown. How do you define a "shift"? And what are the values of `fromDate` and `toDate`? If those define a "shift", then it's hard to see what the issue is.

Comment: I am guessing this is like a timecard system, where you want to work out how long an employee has worked (speculatively), this is not really as simple as it sounds. Employees can enter and leave, start at weird times, work late at night, go home early, bifurcate a shift, there maybe the concept of multiple shifts, and an employee might work double shifts. You need to constrain the rules

Comment: whelp.. I was going to caution on raising these sort of Time And Attendance system policy configuration issues and considerations (because of the complexity) but it seems that can was opened.

Comment: @00110001 i updated my post i hope it clarifies the confusion.

Comment: @Yajnos this is a lot better than what you started with.

Comment: I checked your code. Your code works correctly. Your code returns the first login and the first logout each day. Where is the problem now? no problem

Comment: @meysamasadi The issue is the night shift it shows both entry as min and max then the exit as both min and max too